# Meaning of "release" in the given context

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

Here is a sentence from an employment agreement:

"In the case of any accident or any other event occurring during the period of employment, the worker releases any and all actions or expenses that they may have as a result."

I am not sure about the meaning of "release" here. It would be a great help if someone could rephrase the sentence above.

Comment: It's poorly worded at best.

Comment: You have to release someone from liability or something else. You cannot "release actions and expenses". This was poorly translated into English. Funny thing, agencies continue to use piss-poor translators or even automatic translation, then, expect that result to be translated into another language or edited. That ends  up being more expensive than paying a good translator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**hold-harmless**   [investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/h/hold-harmless-clause.asp)

> The most common uses of hold harmless clauses occur in real estate and
>   construction. Additionally, businesses engaged in high-risk
>   activities, such as skydiving and certain sports clubs, also make
>   frequent use of such clauses.

As in:

> In case of an accident, the worker will hold harmless (release: not
>   blame or seek recompense) the the employer.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is the legal connotation of [release:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/released)

> (Law.) to give up, relinquish, or surrender (a right, claim, etc.).

(Dictionary.com)